# migrate Old reports to new SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have configured new Server with reporting services 2008 R2,
I have 2 more reporting servers with SQL 2005 and SQL 2008.
How can I move my old reports (with all Subscriptions) to new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used RSScripter application, and transferred all of my reports to new server

http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2009/01/29/using-rs-scripter-to-create-deployment-script-for-reporting-services.aspx

Comment: I was under the impression that rsScripter didn't support 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic867451-162-1.aspx#bm868477).

Since you are merging reports from 2 servers into the new one, you can either copy reports from source control or use SSRS scripter.

Comment: actually I want to merge my servers to 1 SSRS.